# Tag wiki summary sync issue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki

The tag wiki summary for the [[numpy]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) tag appears to be out of sync with what appears on the dynamic content on the https://stackoverflow.com/tags page. The wiki summary currently says "this tag has no wiki summary ...", but I'm pretty sure there should be content there

Is this a result of an edit being in the queue, or is this a genuine problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Actually, [/tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page is looking for excerpt, while [/tag/tagname](https://stackoverflow.com/tag/c%23) is looking for wiki summary.

If you take a look at the other tags, for example [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), you'll see that in /tags it's

> a high level, general-purpose object-oriented programming language created by Microsoft.

in [/questions/tagged/c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), it's different, too

> C# is a multi-paradigm, managed, object-oriented programming language created by Microsoft in conjunction with the .NET platform. C# is also used with non-Microsoft implementations (most notably, Mono). Versions 1.0/1.2 and 2.0 of C# were submitted and approved as both ECMA and ISO/IEC standards. ...

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/9) and I think you'll get what am I talking about

Answer (score 3):

I am currently quite confused about tag wikis, tag wiki excerpts, tag summaries, and how they are supposed to work. Recently, changes have been silently introduced (for the worse, IMHO). See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120946/155793).

The [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) wiki summary does say "this tag has no wiki summary ..." as the OP points out. I am pretty sure this wasn't the case a couple of weeks ago.