# Aren't suggested edits for tag wikis not reported as activity anymore?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

On Meta Stack Overflow, I made two suggested edits for two different tags, but they are not shown as activity, under "suggestion."

The last suggestions reported are from February, and December.

[image: screenshot]

I remember that pending suggested edits were shown as activity, and they were reported as pending instead of *approved*, or *rejected*.

The tag page says the tag doesn't have a wiki summary.

[image: screenshot]

I also tried editing again the same tag wiki, and the editor shown me the previous text I entered, even if the page doesn't shown the "thank you for your edit" text I normally see when I suggest an edit.

[image: screenshot]

Aren't suggested edits for tag wikis not reported as activity anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have over 20K, which means that your tag wiki edits no longer have to go through the suggested edit process because you [have the privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) to edit all tag wikis on the site.

The edits are still activity of course, but you'll now find them [under the revisions tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140449/kiamlaluno?tab=activity&sort=revisions):

[image: revision history items]

As to why there's nothing displayed for the tag wiki excerpt, the text shown there is [now taken from the tag wiki body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120946/the-excerpts-at-the-top-of-tag-question-lists-have-been-replaced-by-the-first-f), although there's [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122933/display-the-tag-wiki-excerpt-when-the-tag-wiki-is-empty) to still use the explicit excerpt text in cases where the body is empty.

Comment: That is correct. I guess I was confused from the tag page saying the tag didn't have a tag summary, which led me to think the edit was automatically rejected for some reason (as it was reported in a different question).

Comment: Yeah, I updated the answer with relevant links on the lack of tag wiki summary.