# Can a tags list constitute a glossary?

Tags: discussion, tags, glossary

I realize that **tags**

- help to categorize and organize questions
- have "short" and "long" (my words) definitions, descriptions or discussions

Both are great qualities and yet there seems to be an overall emphasis or policy towards using *existing* tags rather than adding new ones.

I believe a comprehensive set of tags, along with their definitions, descriptions or discussions, constitutes a very useful knowledge-base *on its own*, and may even render certain questions unnecessary.

So, **why not expand the role of the tag system to become a glossary?**

How many times have you seen a question that could have been answered simply by browsing some tags?

If there is a consensus on the expansion of tags' purpose towards a glossary, further questions would have to be addressed: how to handle topic hierarchies, examples, cross-references, antonyms, (synonyms have already been discussed), etc. Those questions can wait, however.

Comment: But what about tags that fit under various other tags?! How exactly can we *categorize* such tags? Like the idea though.

Comment: I just appended a paragraph on that question, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you want this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176417/mark-questions-as-duplicate-of-tag-wiki

Comment: @random -- Sorry, i don't understand your point. Is that Q&A supposed to deal with my Q? I see it is _related_ but far less so than http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136077/have-stack-overflows-tag-wiki-excerpts-veered-away-from-their-purpose?rq=1 for example.

Comment: Given the amount of duplicates in the system you assume users either search or care that the information already exists

Comment: _If_ there were greater emphasis placed on the tag system, yes, i would assume users would care more about it. But what do you mean by "duplicates in the system"?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122197/tag-wikis-need-a-size-and-functionality-increase

Comment: @random : Any idea on how i can improve my question? (I'm facing a ban and need to improve my questions.) Thanks.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil : Any idea on how i can improve my question? (I'm facing a ban and need to improve my questions.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Tags already do constitute a glossary.

Definition of glossary:

> "an alphabetical list of terms or words found in or relating to a specific subject, text, or dialect, with explanations; a brief dictionary."

## **[`Tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)**

Screenshot of Tags page

[image]

or sorted alphabetical

[image]

Sure, there could be more definitions filled in, but still, people edit information into tag wikis all the time.

*New Tags*

The reason that the use of new tag names is frowned upon is because if every word were allowed to become a tag, then it would be more like a dictionary, not a glossary. The value of tags would significantly decrease.

*Duplicate questions*

The [linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176417/mark-questions-as-duplicate-of-tag-wiki) from [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213415/can-a-tags-list-constitute-a-glossary#comment687192_213415) seems to make some sense in *expanding the role of tags* in that perhaps questions could be closed as "Question addressed in tag wiki" or similar.

Comment: Tags already a Glossary. Maybe. If so, Can we have a better glossary?

Comment: Too many new tags = Dictionary. Maybe, but the name and definition of the particular SE should imply the level of generality and detail appropriate.

Comment: Close Q with "already answered in tag" message. Yes, i guess that would be needed as a small addition to the SE capability.

Answer (score 0):

While the [tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) might look as a glossary, tags can't be used as a glossary because there were already several discussions about tag hierarchies. So far, according to  [tag-hierarchy](/questions/tagged/tag-hierarchy) all of them were "declined". Tag excerpt the referred tag:

> Tags on Stack Exchange aren't hierarchically ordered (and, in all likelihood, will never be - several proposals have been made already). Please check the list in the tag wiki to see if your question/proposal has already been asked before

The main purpose of tags is to connect questions with answerers not to be something to be read before posting a question, otherwise, the ask a question page should include a step for self-reviewing  the *tag - question concordance*.

Related

- [Should we have a "glossary" of tag related terms coined by the community that are commonly used across SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353220/289691)