# Is this the meta site for SO or for the whole SE family?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Yes, I know there is this [why-is-stack-overflows-meta-also-the-meta-of-the-whole-stack-exchange-engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96313/why-is-stack-overflows-meta-also-the-meta-of-the-whole-stack-exchange-engine) question, but the tone of the answer seems to perpetuate the notion that other, non-IT SE sites don't actually matter.

For example, I asked [can-a-tags-list-constitute-a-glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213415/can-a-tags-list-constitute-a-glossary) and was referred to [mark-questions-as-duplicate-of-tag-wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176417/mark-questions-as-duplicate-of-tag-wiki) which was so full of C++ and PHP references that I failed to even see how it was related, even after a couple of readings.

If I come here for some honest Q&A about policies and procedures relevant to the whole family of SE sites and I'm met with a load "pure" SO jargon/examples I wonder why it is labelled as something different.

I'm aware of the history (that, In the beginning, there was Stack Overflow) but that doesn't justify the general state of confusion of this, MSO, site.

Comment: It is confusing, and [it will change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own).

Comment: Could you give some examples

Comment: @RichardTingle -- Yes. I just asked http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213415/can-a-tags-list-constitute-a-glossary and was referred to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176417/mark-questions-as-duplicate-of-tag-wiki which was so full of C++, PHP, Reference that i failed to even see how it was related, even after a couple of readings.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta -- That is a good (the right?) Answer, thanks.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, I'm not still seeking an answer to this rather now-irrelevant question, i'm merely on a (futile?) mission to "improve" my questions, to appease the gods in the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once upon a time, Stack Overflow **was** the network so its meta site and the network meta site were the same.

As it stands now, this meta has two hats:

1. The per site meta of Stack Overflow, place to report bugs specific only to that site, discuss things related to it etc.
2. The whole Stack Exchange network "meta" i.e. place to report bugs affecting more than one site, discuss general things that do not concern one specific site etc.

However, [this is all going to change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/152859), soon. <sup>✝</sup>

<sup><sub><sup>✝</sup> 6-8 weeks</sub></sup>

Answer (score -2):

*Note that Stack overflow now has its own meta and this is now only the meta site for the entire network*

Original answer:

This is the appropriate site for issues which affect all sites, or specifically effect stack overflow; either can be discussed here. Site specific issues for other sites should be discussed in their own metas.

Of course as the flagship site stack overflow examples are always going to be common but any general issue can be discussed.

There are discussions as to seperating out these two separate parts of the site, as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own)

Comment: True, but that's not an answer to my very specific question.

Comment: The question "Is this the meta site for SO or for the whole SE family?"? Yes it does (although the situation has changed in the interviening years such that SO has a placw of its own now)

Comment: If you bothered to *read the whole question*, not just the *title*, you'd have noticed i already *knew* your "answer". My title-as-question was rhetorical.

Comment: I thought you might say that: whats the actual question you were asking in the rest of the post. The rest feels more like a letter of complaint (which at the very least needs a proposal in it)

Comment: Also; this was a year ago, the question doesn't even make sense anymore! This isn't Meta stack overflow