# When tag wiki excerpt does not exist, but tag wiki does, some messages/activities are misleading

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

The situation happens when there is an approved tag wiki, but no approved tag excerpt.

Here you can see it on the tag [packaging](/questions/tagged/packaging):

[image]

It seems the message "tag has no wiki summary" is subordinated at the tag wiki excerpt existence.

[image: screen shot]

**Also**, when clicking the "learn more button" the following message appears:

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!...

This is not true either.

**Proposal**.

1. When there is not a tag wiki excerpt, replace "tag has no wiki summary" for "tag has no wiki excerpt".
2. Whenever the tag wiki exists (the detailed one), enable the "learn more" button to direct the page to the tag wiki content.

Comment: The current behavior is certainly weird +1

Comment: A tag wiki summary without an excerpt do not exist. You edit both (excerpt and summary) when editing the tag wiki entry.

Comment: @AndreSilva I updated the bug description

Comment: Hmm, this was [broken and fixed a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122933/135887).  Is the new behavior intentional?  I hadn't even noticed...