# Tag excerpts not showing

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The excerpts at the top of tag question lists have been replaced by (the first few lines of) the text of the full tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120946/the-excerpts-at-the-top-of-tag-question-lists-have-been-replaced-by-the-first-f)

Seems to me that the excerpt is not being used, but rather a truncated version of the full tag description.

Note in particular the stray "The basics" in the following (taken from [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)):

[image: image displaying Tag info contrasted with excerpt use on tagged page]

Comment: This is by design. Hang on while I try to dredge up an official statement from waffles.

Comment: The tag pages show the beginning of the Tag Wiki, the excerpt is used when you hover over a tag. Note also there's a mechanism whereby the tag excerpt is trimmed if it uses other tags at the start.

Comment: Couldn't find an official statement, but did find a duplicate.

Comment: I see.  Apologies.