# Tag wiki excerpts not showing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt, specific-site

Over on [Aviation](http://aviation.stackexchange.com), some of [our tags](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags?page=11&tab=popular) aren't showing their excerpts unless you hover on them, for example [atc](/questions/tagged/atc), [cvr](/questions/tagged/cvr), [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states). Note that [iacc](/questions/tagged/iacc) is correct:

[image]

Note that this is unrelated to this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120946/the-excerpts-at-the-top-of-tag-question-lists-have-been-replaced-by-the-first-f) where the excerpts weren't showing due to showing the main body instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tags in question are all synonyms of other tags; the excerpt is on the target (long) tag (i.e. [air-traffic-control](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-traffic-control)), not the synonym.

If I recall correctly, the synonyms don't show the inherited excerpt there to downplay their visual significance in the list, but I'm admittedly not positive I'm not just imagining that reasoning.